# Why can 'for (a of a)' iterate an array correctly?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code snippets

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (a of a) { // The first 'a' is made by mistake
    console.log(a);
}
```

The first `a` in the `for` loop is written by mistake. I think the above code should run error, because when `a` is assigned to `1` in the first iteration, then `a` is not *iterable object*. So an error should be thrown out in the next iteration.

Actually, the results are as following:

```
1
2
3
4
```

It seems the above code can iterate the array correctly. After the `for` loop, the result of `a` is `4`. **Why?**

```
> a
4
```

For further investigation, I tried to find some information from [`ECMA-6 doc`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements), but I am confused by the following statement.

> *for ( var ForBinding of AssignmentExpression ) Statement*
>
> *for ( ForDeclaration of AssignmentExpression ) Statement*

To understanding the `ForBinding` and `ForDeclaration`, test the following code.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (var a of a) {
    console.log(a);
}
console.log(a);
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same as the previous codes. What is the difference between `for (var a in a)` and `for (a in a)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`for` evaluates value of "AssignmentExpression" and iterates over it. The value is obtained only once in the beginning of iteration, so reusing the same variable is perfectly valid (also quite confusing).

Presence of `var`: `for (a of ...)` and `for (var a of ...)` does not make any <sup>1</sup> difference in code as you already have `a` defined - so it will just re-declare the same variable.

---

To be completely precise there are cases where behavior is different - when `a` is declared in outer scope for current function `var` version will shadow that value (as in JavaScript all `var` statements are hoisted to top of the function scope):

```
var a = [1,2,3];
function tryForVar()   {
   // Note that declaration of `a` is hoisted here as var a = undefined;
   // for (var a ... does not work as expected as local 'a' is undefined
   for (var a of a) { 
     console.log(a); // log 'undefined' once
   }
   console.log(a); // undefined 
} 
tryForVar();
console.log(a); // [1,2,3]

function tryFor()   {
   // Note that declaration of `a` from outer scope
   // for (a ... works fine as it uses outer 'a'
   for (a of a) { 
     console.log(a); // logs all 1,2,3 in sequence
   }
   console.log(a); // 3
} 
tryFor();
console.log(a); // 3
```

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that actually addresses the question and appears to also be the only correct answer.  Not sure why someone else gave it a downvote.  +1 from me.

Comment: I didn't vote down, but variables declared with `var` are not re-declared. Declarations are hoisted in their scope, and `var`s met later in the code are _ignored_.

Comment: @Teemu yes, my statement is indeed oversimplification and instead should be "if you use `var a` version the meaning of `a` before and after loop will still be the same, but it may shadow variables from outer scope due to hoisting (and hence completely change what you are iterating over)".

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. The AssignmentExpression is not read only once at the beginning of iteration. You can change values in the array during a for .. of loop to see that is not the case.

Comment: @JayChase value of the expression in the case shown by OP is array itself - it is not a *copy of the array*. As result you can still change content of the array (as long as you have other reference to it). Maybe imagining temporary variable that used to store result of the expression is a way to visualize what is happening. Note that what happens when code is changing array/object while iterating over is very hard to predict for most people to - try to avoid it.